# webgl doesn't work on crosswalk framework for Android

Tags: android, webgl, crosswalk-runtime

I've trying all the samples of the Crosswalk engine and also compiled myself the sample project but I couln't make WebGl work in Crosswalk
And it suposes to work
Here  is the tutorial I've been following
http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/blogs/2014/01/02/developing-android-apps-using-intel-xdk-and-threejs

with the apk at the bottom

Also here I've downloaded the sample and compiled  it myself 
https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk-samples-0.1.tgz

I tryed with the development and the stable version and in a Nexus 5, Nexus 10 with Android 4.4
Also with a Samsung tablet with Android 4.2.2
Nothing seems to work.
Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you publish the version of crosswalk being used, and also the adb logs if you are able to connect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, currently we follow up Chromium gpu blacklist. However, we're planning to enable command line which allows developers to enable webGL on all devices by themselves. See
https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-1269

Comment: I've seen that command line is enabled now. I didn't try yet but it should work

Comment: @butelo where do I put the ignore-gpu-blacklist command for a crosswalk cordova project?