# Ionic webgl support issue

Tags: android, cordova, webgl, ionic-framework

I need webgl for android and ios to work. Right now I am just focusing on android. From my understanding if I download crosswalk webgl should work.

> https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html

So I added crosswalk o my project with the command:

```
ionic browser add crosswalk
```

and everything seemed to install fine. The layout now looks a little different and scrolling has improved. The problem is when I try to use webgl it gives a black box in my app and it says this browser doesn't support webgl. Is there anything else I need to do?

As a second option I looked into cocoonjs which also apparently supports webgl.

> https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/

I removed crosswalk and installed cocoonjs with the command

```
ionic plugin add com.ludei.webview.plus -d
```

and everything seems to install fine. Then I tried to run my app and I got the same result saying my browser doesn't support webgl.

Has anyone got webgl support to work with the ionic framework and if so how?

Comment: Which browser your used?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean. I am using the most up to date crosswalk so I am using the version of chrome it comes with.

Comment: Check here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090097/webgl-doesnt-work-on-crosswalk-framework-for-android

Answer (score 1):

Locate the config.xml file in the root of your project. Inside it, locate the this line and add `--ignore-gpu-blacklist`

```
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect --ignore-gpu-blacklist"/>
```

Tested in Android

Answer (score 0):

Because some device is in blacklist of running WEBGL. Check here for solution:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/webgl-not-working/28274